# 413 error when I add image to post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, http-status-code-413

want to add a user to MongoDB with a profile picture as base64, username, and password but when I send the request with username and password it works because I don't require a profile picture but when I send it with the picture the problem below appears

When I try to post a request with the username & password only it worked and gets saved in MongoDB but when I add an image using Filebase64 this error appears in the console when I send

[image]
I try to add  **bodyParser.urlencoded** and add **CORS**  but nothing help

[image]

this is Sign Up hook: **I also try to add cors: 'no-cors' to the request but change nothing**

[image]

in terminal I get PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large only when send the image without it every thing work perfectly

Comment: The backend is telling you the file you're uploading is too large.

Comment: yes that's clear from the message I get, is there any solution I try raising the limit to a bigger value but nothing helps

Comment: how big is the file you're trying to upload?

Comment: 200kb less than the limit

Comment: Base64 encoding is inefficient and blows up the size. Try doubling the limit and see if that works.